# Loading PHP function using jQuery onclick

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am trying to hide our mailing address on our website, until someone cliks a button to "load" the address. I am doing it like follows:

Homepage.php:

```
<button onclick="test()"> Click </button>
<div> </div>
<script>
function test(){
    $.ajax({url:"address.php", success:function(result){
    $("div").text(result);}
})
} 
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Address.php:

```
<?php
function php_func(){
    echo '<span><?php echo $address; ?></span>';
}
php_func();
?>
```

This works in echoing the *text* onto homepage.php, but it's not loading the PHP function. Just showing the function as text as seen here:
[image]

I tried `$("div").write(result);}` and it won't even load.

$address is already defined elsewhere. Any tips?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$address` in `address.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write code which outputs code which outputs the address.  Why?  You're already in the context of outputting something from the PHP code:

```
echo "something...";
```

If what you want to output is the value of `$address` then just output that:

```
echo "<span>$address</span>";
```

---

I **suspect** the reason you did it that way is because you're expecting *the currently loaded page* to parse and execute that PHP code.  This is a fundamental misunderstanding of how these technologies work.  The PHP code for that page executed once, on the server, and delivered the resulting HTML/CSS/JavaScript to the client.

The AJAX operation is making a new, separate request to another PHP resource which will execute on the server and output back to the client.  In this case it's just outputting a string value, which the client-side JavaScript code will then write to an element on the page:

```
$("div").text(result);
```

(This is a good opportunity for you to use your browser's debugging tools and observe the AJAX request/result in the network tab, to see what's actually being sent/received.  At *no point* should actual PHP code be visible to the browser.  All of that is executed on the server.)

The reason this is important is because, if this is the case, then you are likely misunderstanding where `$address` is defined.  If it's defined in the PHP script which rendered the page you're looking at, that doesn't mean it's defined in `address.php`.  If the code you're showing us for `address.php` is the entirety of that page then `$address` **is not defined**.

So you'll need to define `$address` on that page.

---

After having said all of that... You might find it much easier not to involve AJAX for this at all in the first place.  Just output the address to the page but style the `<span>` to not be visible.  Then when the user clicks the button, make it visible.  No need for the complexity of an entirely new HTTP request:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('span').show();
});
```

```css
span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<span>this is the address</span>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for your time. I did assume homepage would load $addresses as it's defined there, NOT on address.php. The reason I don't just hide the address, is because I want it less easily scraped.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `<?php echo` inside strings; that's only used when you're in a section of the script that's outputting literal text, not executing PHP code.

If you're in PHP code doing `echo`, you use variable substitution or concatenation.

```
<?php
function php_func(){
    echo "<span>$address</span>";
}
php_func();
?>
```

You'll need additional code to set the `$address` variable; I assume you just left that out for simplification in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function php_func(){
    echo '<span>' . $address .'</span>';
}
php_func();
?>
```

this should work, u can't use 'echo' and inside echo open 'php' tag to use again.... more another 'echo'

Comment: Ah, that is correct! Though weirdly enough it's still parsing the <spans> as text not HTML. Wrapping them in ""